# How to change the default field name for a Java Annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I'm trying to implement a custom annotation for tests. The annotation will be something like the spock's annotation `@Issue`.

I want to change the default field name for the annotation. For example:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@ExtensionAnnotation(IssueExtension.class)
public @interface Issue {
 
  String[] value();
}
```

This is a standard declaration of annotation but is it possible to change the default field `value` with a different name? For example `initial`. So when I say `@Issue("TICKET-XXXX")` <- this value will be applied to the `initial` field instead of the `value` without the need to write `@Issue(initial = "TICKET-XXXX")`

Comment: The specific thing you want to do can't be done, but maybe if you gave us some context as to **why** you want to change the name (the name of a field which is rarely mentioned shouldn't matter a lot), then we could come up with alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that.

`value` is specified to be the name of the field which gets values when no field name is specified. See [JLS §9.7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.3):

> A single-element annotation is a shorthand designed for use with single-element annotation interfaces (§9.6.1).
>
> ```
> SingleElementAnnotation:
>   @ TypeName ( ElementValue )
> ```
>
> It is shorthand for the normal annotation:
>
> ```
> @TypeName(value = ElementValue)
> ```